# C# checkbox eventhandler

Tags: c#, checkbox

```
    private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        SetValuesInDB( System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name,
                       DateTime.Today.Date);

    }
```

Now I want to setvalues of my id and current date in database only if I directly clicked on the checkbox.

I dont want to update those values in Database if some other event triggers this event handler. 
For eg: while loading everytime the checkbox gets checked but the database value for this checkbox is unchecked.
so, everytime this event handler is triggered and database value is updated. 
How do I take care of it?

Comment: Can you try to explain your question a little better. When you say "while loading everytime the checkbox..." what loading are you referring to? Are you ever calling this method directly?

Comment: @BFree: His reference to "loaded every time" likely refers to the forms *Load* event or *OnLoad* override where it's typical to put initialization code, such as populating checkboxes.  Unless he also wants to exclude keyboard interaction from triggering his logic, the only answer to date should work for him...

Answer (score 4):

Use the CheckBox.Click event instead.   It gets fired if either the user clicks on the checkbox or uses Space to toggle the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do.

If you want the value in the database and userinterface to be always up to date you might try DataBindings...

```
internal class MyDataSource {

    public bool MyBooleanValue {
        get { return ReadValueFromDB("MyUser", "MyBool"); }
        set { SaveValueToDB("MyUser", value); }
    }

}

...

internal class MyControl {


    internal MyControl() {
        dataSource = new MyDataSource();

        InitializeComponents();

        myCheckbox.DataBindings.Add(
            "Checked", dataSource, "MyBooleanValue"
        );
    }

    private MyDataSource dataSource;

}
```

otherwise you might wish to write the value only in the database when the user finishes an operation. Such as closing event handler of a form or okButton click event handler.